# How to customize a ui-grid table?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am trying to customize the grid menu for angular ui grid 
By default the menu icon appears in the top right corner of the table. But i want to show it on the top left corner of the table. How can i configure this?
Also I want to change the default icon to a customized one.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something supported by the API, so you will have to do it by changing some of the CSS:

```
.ui-grid-menu-button {
   left: -21px;
   width: 20px;
}

.ui-grid-menu-button .ui-grid-menu{
   left: -11px;
   top: 27px;
}
```

To change the icon you will have to edit:

```
.ui-grid-icon-menu:before {
   content:'\c363'; 
}
```

to whatever you want.